# Write a Macro to stringify the contents of a struct

Tags: c++, struct, stringify

I am trying to write a macro to expand the contents of a struct:

```
struct Str
{
    int a;
    float f;
    char *c;
};
Str s = {123, 456.789f, "AString"};

#define STRINGIFY_STR(x) ... // Macro to stringify x which is an instance of Str

printf("%s", STRINGIFY_STR(s));
```

desired output: [a: 123, f:456.789, c:AString]

Is it possible to write a macro that does this? If it is, then how?

Comment: stringify? macros? Why not simply add a `toString` method to your object or a free function which takes a const reference to achieve this? You could even just use `std::ostringstream` if performance is not a concern.

Comment: IS there a particular reason you need a macro? It would be better to write `operator<<` for the Str class.

Answer (score 6):

Is there a reason you want to do this as a macro?

You should write a function to perform this action instead of using the preprocessor.

---

Depending on your goals, there are a few options.  The [boost formatting library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/format/index.html) provides a great toolkit to build the formatted string.  You could always [overload `operator<<`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) to provide clean output, as well.

If you're doing this in pure C, the [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) family of methods work for creating formatted output.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, It could use a bit of code, but in the end it's the same syntax (or better) for a working output or string.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I tried to add some useful information for options -but I guess my problem is that I feel that directly answering the question is promoting something that's a bad practice in general.

Comment: I don't want to write a function for this because then I would have to allocate memory dynamically or pass a buffer to the function to hold the string. I just thought it could be possible to expand the struct into a string with a macro, am I wrong?

Comment: @FearLeslie Even with a macro, you'd be creating a buffer of some form to hold the string data, even if it's on the stack.  How is that different than passing a stack allocated buffer?

Comment: @FearLeslie Don't "fear" unnecessarily :-)

Comment: @Reed Copsey: may be you are right. Still, out of curiosity, how would one go about writing such a macro?

Comment: @FearLeslie The macro would just be building a string - so any of the techniques you'd use to do it in a function would have to be expanded into the macro.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite gross, and only works on `gcc`/`g++`.

```
#define STRINGIFY_STR(x) \
    std::string(({ std::ostringstream ss; \
                   ss << "[a: " << x.a \
                      << ", f: " << x.f \
                      << ", c: " << x.c << "]"; \
                   ss.str(); })).c_str()
```

You have to create the string from the values. Please don't do it this way. Please follow Reed's advice.

Here is how I would modify your `struct` to allow it to be pretty printed:

```
struct Str
{
    int a;
    float f;
    char *c;

    std::ostream & dump (std::ostream &os) const {
        return os << "[a: " << a
                  << ", f: " << f
                  << ", c: " << c << "]";
    }
};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &os, const Str &s) {
    return s.dump(os);
}

Str s = {123, 456.789f, "AString"};
```

Now, to print out `s`, you can use `std::cout`:

```
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Or, if you really want a string:

```
std::stringstream ss;
s.dump(ss);
puts(ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it does look ugly. May be writing a member function would be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct stringify
{
    operator std::string() const
    {
        return str ;
    }
    std::string str ;
};

template < typename T > stringify operator+ ( stringify s, const T& object )
{
    std::ostringstream stm ;
    stm << object ;
    if( !s.str.empty() && !std::isspace( *s.str.rbegin() ) ) s.str += ' ' ;
    s.str += stm.str() ;
    return s ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also against the approach, but to answer the question:

```
#define STRINGIFY_STR(x) \
   (std::string("[a: ") + std::to_string((long double)x.a) \
  + std::string(", f:") + std::to_string((long double)x.f) \
  + std::string(",c: ") + x.c + std::string("]") ).c_str()
```

I suggest writing a member function that does this though.